# SQL/Oracle: Select min and max column values for each unique value in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, max, unique, min

Lets say I have the following data

```
CODE   TYPE
1      1
2      1
6      1
8      1
10     1
2      2
3      2
5      2
9      2
11     2
```

How can I go about getting the min and max CODE for each unique value of TYPE?  Basically I want the query to produce the following:

```
MIN    MAX   TYPE
1      10    1
2      11    2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `type` and use the aggregate functions `min()` and `max()`

```
select min(code) as min,
       max(code) as max,
       type
from your_table
group by type
```